# merging two arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am tying to merge two arrays in JS, and then sort them. The following code will output the two arrays on the page, but ONLY if I remove the "newArr.sort();" line. Otherwise, I get nothing. Can anyone help a newbie here?

```
function merge(arr1, arr2){

var arr1 = [1,21,13,24,15];
var arr2 = [16,7,81,59,14];
var newArr = "[ ]"; 

arr1.sort();
arr2.sort();
newArr = arr1+","+arr2;
newArr.sort();
document.writeln(newArr);
}
```

Comment: Your `newArr` is a **string** and not an array...

Comment: `[2,1,3].concat([6,4,5]).sort()`...

Comment: You forget the eval: `newArr = eval("["+arr1+","+arr2+"]")`

Comment: @copy lol just **no**.

Comment: `newArr` isn't an array it's a string which is why `newArr.sort()` fails. A better way would be to define `newArr` as an array, use `newArr.concat(arr1,arr2)` and then loop through the array to find duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = [1,21,13,24,15];
var arr2 = [16,7,81,59,14];

var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);

alert(arr3);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRLSs/